# How to convert Spark Dataset Field (Wrapped array) to Map or List of Array in Spark Java

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading a dataset, which has one of the field in WrappedArray of Map, in below format.

```
[WrappedArray(Map(F1 -> V1, F2 -> V2, F3 -> V3), Map(F1 -> V1, F2 -> V2, F3 -> V3), Map(F1 -> V1, F2 -> V2, F3 -> V3))]
```

How can I convert that to a List or Map of values? I am doing it in spark java.

Comment: Could you please sample output?

Comment: WrappedArray(Map(name -> aaa, age -> 010, amount -> 100.00), Map(name -> BBB, age -> 240, amount -> 200.00))